# CURL receive "empty reply from server", but browser receive response. Why?

Tags: django, rest, nginx, curl, request

I set up rest-api server. (Django 1.11 + NGINX + Gunicorn + Postgresql 9.6)

For testing, I developed simple API. Get request URL /test, then respond "success" string. In web browser, it worked well.

But when I request same url with CURL, I receive "curl: (52) Empty reply from server". I tried curl on other remote server, and I tried curl http://127.0.0.1/test on that server. Both didn't not work. I received "curl: (52) Empty reply from server".

Why it work in web browser, and it not work in CURL? Where should I check? NGIMX? Django? I checked firewell.

Sorry for poor english. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I tried the following,

```
$ curl -vv http://127.0.0.1/test/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: Can you show how you are doing curl?

Answer (score 3):

First add `-vv` to the curl command to see what is happening with the connection. If it says server redirection is happening, add `-L` to solve the problem.